# Display strings with correct spacing

Tags: python

```
Jay Samuel   Tomm Sietsema             1.87   
Jay Samuel   Jonathan Golder             2.87   
Jay Samuel   Brette Anderson             1.58   
Jay Samuel   Michael Baumer              1.8   
Jay Samuel   Corby Kumar             1.5   
Jay Samuel   Pete Wellsworth             2.74
```

I used the following code:

```
print(name,"\t",name2,"\t\t\t",format(round(ans,2)))
```

But still, 1.5 and 1.87 do not appear in line as the other numbers do.

Comment: This is probably because you're using tabs. When the first or second string is too short, tabs will be moved further left. Additionally, try to provide a minimal, reproducible example. We should be able to paste your code into a file and run it.

Comment: Why don't you try figuring out how many characters along you want `ans` to be, and then using `ljust` to left-justify to the desired length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
>>> a = '''Jay Samuel   Tomm Sietsema             1.87   
... Jay Samuel   Jonathan Golder             2.87   
... Jay Samuel   Brette Anderson             1.58   
... Jay Samuel   Michael Baumer              1.8   
... Jay Samuel   Corby Kumar             1.5   
... Jay Samuel   Pete Wellsworth             2.74 '''
>>> data = [t.split() for t in a.split('\n')]
>>> data
[['Jay', 'Samuel', 'Tomm', 'Sietsema', '1.87'], ['Jay', 'Samuel', 'Jonathan', 'Golder', '2.87'], ['Jay', 'Samuel', 'Brette', 'Anderson', '1.58'], ['Jay', 'Samuel', 'Michael', 'Baumer', '1.8'], ['Jay', 'Samuel', 'Corby', 'Kumar', '1.5'], ['Jay', 'Samuel', 'Pete', 'Wellsworth', '2.74']]
>>> for d in data :
...     name1 = ' '.join(d[:2])
...     name2 = ' '.join(d[2:4])
...     print( '%-15s %-20s %s' % (name1, name2, d[4]) )
... 
Jay Samuel      Tomm Sietsema        1.87
Jay Samuel      Jonathan Golder      2.87
Jay Samuel      Brette Anderson      1.58
Jay Samuel      Michael Baumer       1.8
Jay Samuel      Corby Kumar          1.5
Jay Samuel      Pete Wellsworth      2.74
>>>
```

Comment: please test for `a,b,2.44`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/)

```
print(tabulate({"Name": name,"Name2": name2,"value":value}))
```